# ImportError in AirFlow | Python | Symbol not found: _Py_GetArgcArgv |Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, airflow, importerror

I get this error when I type `airflow vesrion` command in terminal. i install airflow from pip in virtual environment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from airflow.models import DAG
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 43, in <module>
    from airflow.models.dag import DAG
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 46, in <module>
    from airflow.executors import LocalExecutor, get_default_executor
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from airflow.executors.base_executor import BaseExecutor # noqa
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 24, in <module>
    import airflow.utils.dag_processing
  File "/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py", line 40, in <module>
    from setproctitle import setproctitle
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Py_GetArgcArgv
  Referenced from: /Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/subham.polpagedar/Desktop/celery_task/venv_celery/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue on macos. It turns out it was related to the python installed through brew.

If you can, try to use this version from python official website: https://www.python.org/downloads/

and use your virtual environment base as the version you just downloaded.

Hope it helps